# How to avoid erasing iPad content when using different iTunes library?

Tags: itunes, ipad

I have the new iPad and I'm using at work and home.

When I sync something at work (by adding some books or music) and after that at home I want to sync games but the iTunes shows me the warning when I plug in the iPad.

[image]

How to avoid this ? Are there some way

Answer (score 1):

Syncing to the home PC iTunes would lead to the iPad data(Music and books from work) getting backed up to the iTunes and you can keep both the data. And again when you attach it to the work PC iTunes, the backup of the iPad(games from home) would get backed up. The total data would be on iPad as well as the both(Home and work) PC iTunes.